# Error when trying to echo an array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I've got a problem. I can't find a proper array in [this json file](http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198132044757/inventory/json/304930/2). When i try this:

```
<?php
$jsonurl = "http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198132044757/inventory/json/304930/2";
$json = file_get_contents($jsonurl);

$arJson = json_decode( $json, true );
echo $arJson[0]
?>
```

it says:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 0

or if i try this:

```
echo $arJson["rgInventory"]
```

it says:

> Notice: Array to string conversion

Where are the arrays in my json file and how to adress them?

Thank you in advance and sorry for my bad english ;)

Jonas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Notice: Undefined offset: 0

You get this error because your array is an associative array, that mean's there is no index 0. For more info take a look at the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

> Notice: Array to string conversion

You get this error, because [echo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) can only output strings not arrays

to see what's in your array, you can use `var_dump()`

```
<?php
$jsonurl = "http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198132044757/inventory/json/304930/2";
$json = file_get_contents($jsonurl);

$arJson = json_decode( $json, true );
echo "<pre>";
var_dump( $arJson );
```

$arJson["rgInventory"] is also an array so you can see the values with:

```
var_dump( $arJson["rgInventory"] );
```

Comment: then what does that mean:  ["269448832002618981"]=> array(5) because when i do `var_dump( $arJson["269448832002618981"] );` it doesn't work... edit: oh i see my mistake...

Comment: you're welcome, take a look here: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php it will help you through the arrays ;)

Answer (score 2):

1) First of all, you should read Steam API documentation to know the structure of coming data.
https://steamcommunity.com/dev

2) Use print_r and var_dump functions to see the structure of your variables.

For example `<pre> <? print_r($arJson) ?>`

Answer (score 2):

you have to use [print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) in order to print an array.
See your result with

```
echo '<pre>';print_r($arJson);
```